# React Native: How to disable jetifier

Tags: react-native, androidx, android-jetifier

I run the following command line

```
npm I jetifier
npx jetify
```

This made `jetifier` enable. How can I disable it?

Comment: pass `--no-jetify` along with `react-native` cmd

Comment: Do you mean that i run `react-native --no-jetify` ? @RajendranNadar

Comment: Yes, if you want to disable it permanently you need to update the gradle file

Comment: When i run that command i get this error `error: unknown option `--no-jetify'` @RajendranNadar

Comment: My bad it is `--no-jetifier` I used it with `react-native run-android --no-jetifier` and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to migrate to AndroidX yet, you can use `-r` flag with `npx jetify` call. Follow the instruction from this link for more detail:
https://github.com/mikehardy/jetifier#to-reverse-jetify--convert-node_modules-dependencies-to-support-libraries